# SVG anime to path

Tags: svg, anime.js

trying to make the clouds move on the path of the SVG but when I do everything the cloud moves off the view part... no idea why this happens.

[this is it on code pen][1]

`enter code here`[1]: https://codepen.io/paul-santi/pen/MWvMaKp

Comment: Please format your post properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is transforms that are causing the problems.  The transforms on both your cloud **and** cloud path, are pushing the cloud away from your desired animation location.

**To fix**

Firstly, any X,Y offset of the cloud from the origin (0,0) will be included when the cloud follows the path.  So the first thing you need to do is move your clouds so that they are at (0,0).

The quick fix I made to solve this was to add a transform back to the origin, by inserting a group element inside `#Cloued2`

```
Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/WNEVbrO

    <g id="cloued2" transform="translate(0 0)">
      <g transform="translate(-1270,-307)">
        <circle id="Ellipse_1-2" data-name="Ellipse 1"  r="36" transform="translate(1198 325)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_2-2" data-name="Ellipse 2"  r="36" transform="translate(1234 325)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_3-2" data-name="Ellipse 3"  r="36" transform="translate(1270 325)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_4-2" data-name="Ellipse 4" r="36" transform="translate(1306 325)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_5-2" data-name="Ellipse 5"  r="36" transform="translate(1342 325)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_6-2" data-name="Ellipse 6"  r="36" transform="translate(1306 289)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_7-2" data-name="Ellipse 7" r="36" transform="translate(1270 289)" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle id="Ellipse_8-2" data-name="Ellipse 8"  r="36" transform="translate(1234 289)" fill="#fff"/>
      </g>
    </g>
```

The next problem is the `transform` that `#Path_Cloued2` has.  anime.js will be reading the path definition, but won't be taking account of tht transform. So the cloud will be animating somewhere else on the page.

To fix that problem, I removed the `transform` and adjusted the path definition to compensate.

*Old*

```
<path id="Path_cloued2" data-name="Path cloued2" d="M2323,184l712-25-328,75Z" transform="translate(-2069 114)" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
```

*New*

```
<path id="Path_cloued2" data-name="Path cloued2" d="M254,298 l 712-25 -328,75Z" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/>
```

Now the cloud follows the path.  It still does some odd things, but I suspect that's just a matter of adjusting your animation configuration.  Ie. slow it down, and change the easing function to linear.

Comment: Hey, Paul thank you for the help. I just have one question for you because I'm confused about how you adjusted the path definition to compensate? like did you just mess around with the numbers till it looked right?

Comment: No.  The transform was just a simple translate, and the path uses relative path commands. So all I had to do was add the transform X and Y coordinates to the coordinates of the initial (non-relative) Move (M) command. `2323 - 2069 = 254` and `184 + 114 = 298`.  Although I just realised I made a typo and put the wrong Y coord in my second path snippet. Sorry for any confusion. I've fixed it now.